# Android subtitle language support

Tags: android, subtitle

I want to know what are the current subtitle/languages supported in android jb and kitkat.How
can we know which languages and which fonts are supported in respective android versions.

Regards,
Mayank

Answer (score 0):

The supported languages for each version are available in the SDK resources which you can install via SDK manager. The location of the string resources is here:

```
adt-bundle/sdk/platforms/android-##/data/res/values*
```

- ## = API version e.g. android-19 is API 19
- values* = e.g. values-de/strings.xml

You can reference the strings in your code doing this:

```
getString(android.R.string.yes)
```